# What are some specific applications of finite state automata?

Tags: finite-automata

There are several topics discussing finite state automata, but none that I've seen that go into detail about real world applications.  What are some concrete examples of finite state automata in action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most popular application of FSMs are parsers of various kind.

As for real life example is my markup (HTML/XML) parser (tokenizer to be precise): 
[HTML_XML_Scanner](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/HTML_XML_Scanner.aspx)